# turn off UIPickerView gradient

Tags: ios, uipickerview, calayer, mask

I created a `UIPickerView` that I would like to not have that fade on the edges.

First I thought that must be some kind of gradient overlay so I recursively hid all `UIImageViews` within the `UIPickerView` and also set all `layer.contents` to nil. Setting a background color different to white to the picker view reveals that the fade cannot be an overlay, since the labels in the picker view now fade to the background color.

Does anybody have an idea on how to find that layer mask and turn it off?

## EDIT

I just checked if there are any CALayers with masks, but there are none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the answer to my question but at least a solution. I found a custom (horizontal) `AKPickerView` on GitHub which is available for [Obj-C](https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView) and [Swift](https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift) (1.2 and 2.0). This View has an undocumented property `maskDisabled` which does exactly what I need.